# I'm creating a Qlikview report by using data from various tables. Which type of UML diagram will be ideal?

Tags: uml, report

I'm creating a Qlikview report by using data from various tables. 
Which type of UML diagram will be ideal for this scenario?

Comment: It is totally unclear what you are asking here and what you need as a result.

Comment: i'm creating a report jus like that, using data from 2 or 3 tables using Qlikview reporting software. Now i would like to represent this in the form of some UML diagram for easy understanding & documentation. Which UML will best suit for this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Different UML diagram types provide different views onto the same data model. It really depends on what you want to lay your focus on: Interaction of actors? Dynamic behaviour? You generally differentiate structural (class, component, object, ...) and behavioural diagram types (use case, activity, sequence, ...)

Use Case diagrams can offer a simple way of giving a fast overview of what's the general idea of what the model is good for. Class diagrams can show how it is structured internally.
For all the other diagram types, refer to a UML book, there is tons of them out there on the market.

If you want the answer not to be based on very general ideas, I'm afraid you're gonna have to provide more insight to your concrete setup.

Hope this helps...